# How can a random function can be called once and being fixed in another function?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

def test(h,i=-10):
    A=h(i)
    B=h(i)
    return [A,B]


def f(m,n):
    def g(x):
        return np.exp(x)+np.ramdom()-1
    return m*test(g)

print(f(1,2))
```

The problem is that every time the `f` returns it gives a different result, but I want the same result each time. Meaning, every time when I call `test`, I want the `h` parameter to be a fixed function.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before using it.. the tag you used had "DO NOT USE" right at the top of its description. I recognise that you're using Python but don't know the language well enough to determine the version you're using- please edit your question with the version of Python you are using.

Comment: You used random in your code and everytime it changes so how do you want to get same result when you used random?

Comment: @Azhy I just show a simple example, the fact is that g contains several random runs, but after that we need to calculate an equation constructed by those random results. But we hope the equation every time is the same after once running g i.e. keep it fixed when call test. Is this clear for your question?

Comment: @cybermonkey Thanks!

Comment: @xnx Please don't edit the code of a question as it may make the answers redundant.

Comment: @cybermonkey I fixed an obvious typo that was not the cause of the problem OP was trying to solve. The code would not even run to demonstrate the problem they are having without this fix.

Comment: @xnx Thing is, the typo *may have been the problem*. It wasn't in this case, but it's still general consensus not to edit the code in a question even if it does contain a typo and said typo is not the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the seed

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.rand()) # will return same result so long as seed is set to 42
```